# Django AJAX not Rendering Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have a list of devices on an HTML page. The user is able to select a device from that list and click a button to submit that device.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveSelectedRow()" type="submit" name="select" value="Select">Select Device</button>
```

After selecting a row and clicking the button, the following Javascript is called.

```
function saveSelectedRow() {
    var data = getSelectedRow();
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/register/",
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,   // < here
            "data": data,
        }, 
    })
}
```

The AJAX request posts to the following view:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = RegisterDeviceForm()
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'DeviceRegistration/register_device.html', {'form': form})
```

At this point I would like to take the data from the AJAX request and use it to populate the form fields for the request template. I can set breakpoints and watch the following two lines get executed:

```
form = RegisterDeviceForm()
return TemplateResponse('DeviceRegistration/register_device.html', {'form': form})
```

But nothing happens. I have been reading that I may need to render HTML and then use the .success callback of my AJAX request to change the HTML? But, I have not been able to get this working. If I change the two if statement for the two lines above slightly, checking for the name of a different button, the lines execute perfectly and render the template with the form. But using the AJAX request does not have the same functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit#1:

I have changed some code in the request() view:

```
form = RegisterDeviceForm()
return render_to_response('DeviceRegistration/register_device.html', {'form': form})
```

And added a success method to the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/register/",
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,   // < here
        "data": data,
    },
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success!");
    }
})
```

When I inspect the data variable in the success function it contains the HTML that I want to render. I assumed it would be possible to have my Django Python script render the view, but it seems I need to have javascript do it?

Edit#2:

I guess the new question has become how can I have this code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/register/">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getSelectedRow()" type="submit" name="select" value="Select">
          Select Device
     </button>
 </form>
```

Return the data from onclick="getSelectedRow()" to the /register/ page? The code above successfully goes to the register page, but I do not have access to the data that the user selected.

Comment: From [Django's documentation, the syntax for TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects) is TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context). The request seems to be missing here. Also, you can pass `request.POST` in the Form() call to make sure that your Ajax parameters are taken into account. Can you try it this way?

Comment: @raphv That was a copy/paste error from me trying render_to_response (which does not use context). I have edited my original post with the proper TemplateResponse. I also originally had request.POST in my Form() call, but took it out to see if that was causing any errors. With both of those changes the page still does not render.

Comment: What is the response code from the Ajax request? Is it 200 or 500? You should be able to see it in your browser's console, under the network tab.

Comment: The Ajax request is successful. I watch it debug into the register() view. I have also added a success function for the Ajax request, which is executing. I am going to add a small edit to include the details.

Comment: When you say "it contains the HTML that I want to render", what is the problem you have then? It seems everything is successful?
What do you want to do with that HTML? Do you want to do something like `$('body').append(data)`

Comment: That is almost exactly what I want to do, except replace the current HTML with my new HTML. Is there a a replace method? And my original question was before realizing I could pass the HTML back to the Ajax request. I still think it would be more intuitive to simply return the TemplateResponse to the browser, but I guess indirectly I am doing that this way.

Comment: Why are you using Ajax instead of a basic POST form then???

Comment: $('body').html(data) does exactly what I need. I am still very curious why it is necessary to pass the HTML back to the Ajax request and have that render, though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If what I am doing is possible with a basic POST form then I am simply not aware of how. I was using Ajax since it was the most commonly recommended way to take data from one page (selecting a device) and passing it to my views.py script, doing business logic on it, and then rendering a response. If there is a more simple way to do that using Javascript I would love to hear it.

Comment: What happens if you just use a `<form method="POST" action="/register/">` somewhere around your button and no JS? Does it not work?

Comment: It does work, and that is 50% of what I want to do. That successfully lets me click the button to get to the Register page, but how do I pass the selected device data along with it? That was what caused me to use Ajax in the first place, I could get the data and pass it along. You've now convinced me this must be possible, but I am not sure how :)

Comment: I added another edit.

Comment: How about hidden fields? `<input type="hidden" name="device" value="Nexus-6">`. Or if you only have a single value to pass, you can put it directly in the button `<button name="device" type="submit" value="Nexus-6">`

Comment: Hidden fields could work! Is it possible to set the value attribute to the return value of a method? I am attempting it now, but it does not seem possible. Oh, of course, just set the value of the hidden elements in the javascript function. Brilliant! This should work, thanks a lot for your help!